# 6-month limitation

Tags: working-holiday

I am currently working for an employer that owns 3 different business under the same trustee. Once I hit the 6-month mark, am I able to keep working for the same employer, under a different business name and facilities, but with the same ABN number?

Thanks.

Comment: What country are you working in? Australia (suggested by "ABN number")?

Comment: One way to look at these things is this: if it looks like a way around the intentions of the rules, it almost certainly wouldn't be accepted by immigration.  This looks very much like a way around the intention of the rules.

Comment: @Moo If it is an Australian Working Holiday visa, and the work is at different locations, it may confirm to the rules. See [Working in Australia - six months with one employer](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Work/Empl/WHM-six-months-one-employer).